# Jython fetch value from SQL using FDMApi

Tags: sql, oracle, jython

Hi I am using following code to fetch data -

```
query = "Select a from db.data where id=?"
param = 23
ans = fdmAPI.executeQuery(query,param,false)
```

But the value assigned to variable "ans" is weblogic.jdbc.sqlserverbase.dddn@32926500. I dont know what value is this and how to extract data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value returned by the query you will have to use  while (ans.next()): output = ans.getString("a").